# Online test to learn Linux command-line based on frequency of command-line operation and it's methods use?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, testing

Trying to learn Linux command-line as fast as possible, know of any online test that progressively present questions requiring a command be entered. Looking for test that recall what I've answered, and not answered -- and that present command-line based questions based on frequency of command-line operation and it's methods used in the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You... don't really need one. Just install and use Linux. It's free, and there are free virtualization solutions available as well.

Comment: @Ignacio_Vazquez-Abrams: Agreed, but still looking for one. I've been using *nix for 20 years off and on for random projects, and never mastered it's command-lines. Figure an adaptive learning system would push me to learn it.

Comment: Grab a copy of RUTE then, and go through it command by command.

Comment: I doubt anyone could truly master all the available CLI tools available for *nix.  There is far too many overlapping alternatives.